# With Cypress, how to see which files will run without actually running them?

Tags: configuration, cypress

I'm tinkering with my config file to improve my `specPattern` and `excludeSpecPattern`. I think it does what I want but I'd like to check without running my entire test suite to check. I'm calling `cypress run` on the command line with different `--spec` flags for different suites. Is there some way to show all of the files (and ideally a count of tests) that will run without actually running them?

When I start a run, it shows the number of specs found by my patterns, but the list is truncated. I looked through the [Commands docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#Commands) but didn't see a relevant option.

Answer (score 1):

To enable a "dry run" mode, try adding this temporarily to the top of `/cypress/support/e2e.js`

```js
beforeEach(function() {    // use function to gain access to Mocha context (this)
  this.skip()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cypress 10+ and run cypress in open mode in project settings you can see number of Matched test wits specPattern, if you change a save config file it will automatically refresh the application with new config and number of tests.

Comment: Ah, that works for a full run. I should have been more specific: I'm calling `cypress run` on the command line with different `--spec` flags for different suites. I'll update my question. EDIT: actually, no, I was wrong. That shows the count but doesn't show the test files. I can see the count from the command line, but the list of files is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [find-cypress-specs](https://github.com/bahmutov/find-cypress-specs)

> Find Cypress spec files using the config settings
>
> ```
> npx find-cypress-specs 
> # prints all spec files separated by a comma
> cypress/e2e/spec.js,cypress/e2e/featureA/user.js
> ```